# jQuery drag - to get start and stop coordinates

Tags: jquery, drag, mouse-coordinates

Hi I have been looking at jQuery's drag library for a method whereby if I hold the mouse button and drag the mouse, then release the button, I get the start and end coordinates of that drag, based on raw screen pixels. I have drawn a blank on that, and haven't found anything on StackOverlaod either.

Can anyone recommend an example?

Thanks
Graham

Comment: Read the doc on JQuery UI's `.draggable()` API. It explain how to use `.start` and `.stop`. Basically, you will code something like `$("#foo").draggable(){ start:function(){//get coordinates}, stop:function(){//get coordinates}});`. Look at those beautifull examples ^^ http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get the events of dragstart and dragend.
Try this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/css/base.css?v=1">
<style>
    #myDiv
    {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: Red;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myDiv").draggable({
            start: function (e, ui) {
                var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
                var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                $("#start").html(" x: " + relX + ", y: " + relY);
            },
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
                var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                $("#end").html(" x: " + relX + ", y: " + relY);
            }

        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
start Position:<span id="start"></span>
<br />
End Position:<span id="end"></span>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Edited
If you want to get the mouse position without a drag element, use like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").mousedown(function (e) {
            var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
            var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
            var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
            $("#start").html(" x: " + relX + ", y: " + relY);
        });

        $("body").mouseup(function (e) {
            var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
            var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
            var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
            $("#end").html(" x: " + relX + ", y: " + relY);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: If I were to want to drag in an arbitrary part of the screen, without a draggable object, could I do that?